# Deny path to directory from domain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my website set up like this:

```
├─ example.com
|  └─ blog
```

Where my particular hosting control panel doesn't allow me to host my sub-domains elsewhere. Now the `blog/` folder is accessible in two ways:

```
example.com/blog
blog.example.com
```

I don't want the users to access the first path, which would be a security issue for the sub-domains by accessing like this. So I created the `.htaccess` in the root `example.com` folder, this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/blog/? /index.php [L]
```

The above code was suggested in a few posts, but didn't seem to work! Can you please guide me in making sure that the users cannot access the `blog/` folder by navigating to `example.com/blog/`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rule is not going to work. Place this rule as first rule in `/blog/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,R]
```

What it means is that if HOST name isn't starting with `blog.` and request is for any resource in `/blog/` then return `/index.php`.

Comment: Okay, so it goes to my hosting provider's `403` error page. What is the way to redirect to `/index.php`

Comment: it just renders the contents, with the same path. I need a redirect.

Comment: This is full redirect since I used `R` flag here. It will change URL to `domain.com/index.php`

Comment: I guess I missed it. Lemme check again. :)